# Best practise for modeling analytics data

Tags: mongodb, database-design, analytics, data-modeling, bigdata

I am working on a product using which a user can create his/her mobile site. Now, as this is a mobile site creation platform, there are lots of site created in the application. I need to keep all the visitor data in the database so that product can show the analytics to the user of his/her site.

When there was less site, all was working fine. But now the data is growing fast as there are lots of requests on the server. I make use of mongo as NoSQL DBMS to keep all the data. In a collection named "analytics", I usually insert row with site id so that it can be shown to the user. As the data is large, performance to show user analytics is also slow. Also disk space is growing gradually.

What should be best modeling to keep this type of BIG data.

1. Should i create collection per site and store data in separate collection per site ?
2. Should I also separate collection date wise ?
3. What should be the cleaning procedure of the data. What is the best practices adopted by other leader in the industry ?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest reading through MongoDB Optimization strategies at  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/optimization/  . You will find various ways to identify slow performing queries / ops and suggestions to improve them at the mentioned page. Hopefully that should help you resolve slow queries / performance issues.

If you haven't already seen, I would also suggest taking a look at various use cases at http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/ , how they are modeled for those scenarios and if there is any that resembles what you are trying to achieve.

After following through the optimization strategies and making appropriate changes, if you still have performance issues, I would suggest posting following information for further suggestions:

- What is your current state in terms of performance and what is the planned target state?

  - How does your system look i.e. hardware / software characteristics?

Once you have needed performance characteristics, following questions may help you achieve your targets:

- What are the common query patterns and which ones are slow?

  - Potentially look for adding indexes that can enhance query performance
  - Potentially look for schema refactoring based on access patterns
  - Potentially look for schema refactoring for rolling-up / aggregating analytics data based on how it will be used.
- Are writes also slow and is that a concern as well?

  - Potentially plan for Sharding which would provide write as well as read scaling. Sharding is entirely a topic in itself and I would suggest reading about it at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/
- How big the data is and how is it growing or intended to grow

  - Potentially this would give further insights into what could be suggested